# How to check for equality between two RGraphviz objects?

Tags: r

I'm working in R 3.3.1 and I have two RGraphviz objects (directed graphs). I'd like to check if they're equal (all node names and edges match). Is there a function that produces true if they're equal and false otherwise?

Thanks.

Comment: Would `identical` work?

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but it returns `FALSE` for objects that look the same (graph-wise). I'd like the function to return `TRUE` on those, though.

I'm guessing it returns `FALSE` on things that might have different edge weights...

Comment: Maybe try accessing the just the `edgeL` slot (using `g@edgeL`) and using `identical`. You need to consider sort order also, as `identical` cares about order.